# Mysql split time to the time slots in a query

Tags: php, mysql, timeslots

I have a MySQL table with available times:

```
ID  from   till   day
1   540    720    1
2   780    960    1
...
```

The from and till times are simply the minutes from the midnight, e.g. 9AM = 9*60 = 540 and so on.

The `from` and `till` times may vary for different providers and the time slots can be different too.

What I need to do is to make a query that selects results from this table split into the time slots.

For example, one time slot is 60 minutes and the results should look like this:

```
from   till   day
540    600    1
600    660    1
660    720    1
780    840    1
...
```

Do you have an idea on how I can do that in MySQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, there should be **840**

Comment: There's PHP tag, so I assume you are using PHP in this project. This task will be handled better by scripting language (like PHP) than by MySQL alone.

Comment: Yah, I was thinking about that but this query will also need a couple of joins to return the right data. For example every time slot that has an appointment should return an appointment details too.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table with all of the time slots in a day.  It would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE time_slots (
    time_slot_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    start_time INT(11),
    end_time INT(11)
);
```

Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT   ts.start_time, ts.end_time, avt.day

FROM     available_times AS avt

         JOIN time_slots ts
         ON avt.from <= ts.end_time AND avt.till >= ts.start_time

ORDER BY ts.start_time;
```

Comment: The problem is that time slots may vary for different providers and creating another table won't be very efficient.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Why don't you add some more info to the question regarding the time slots to give people a better idea on how they work.  For example is it just the length of time that varies by provider?  Or do the start/end times vary also?

Comment: Yeah the start/end time also. Right now I'm thinking about generating time slots for the availability time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what all your JOINS would be since I don't know your schema but based on the limited information I believe this would be helpful.

If there was a table of time slots as shown below with a foreign key PROVIDER_ID it might look like this. I have included DATETIME fields because these fields might help you out when trying to query on an exact time if a slot was say 35 minutes or something like that. MySQL comes with some DATE functions that could help you out instead of trying to use FROM and TILL in minutes. (I have left FROM and TILL in this example but these would probably not be needed)

Given the following table:

TABLE: time_slots

```
ID  FROM TILL DAY FROM_TIME             TO_TIME              PROVIDER_ID
1   540  630  1   2015-01-03 09:00:00   2015-01-03 10:30:00  4
2   780  960  1   2015-01-03 13:00:00   2015-01-03 16:00:00  16
3   600  660  2   2015-01-03 10:00:00   2015-01-03 11:00:00  7
4   660  720  1   2015-01-03 11:00:00   2015-01-03 12:00:00  9
5   780  840  2   2015-01-03 13:00:00   2015-01-03 14:00:00  12
6   600  630  3   2015-01-03 10:00:00   2015-01-03 10:30:00  14
```

TABLE: providers

```
ID  NAME
4   Provider 4
7   Provider 7
9   Provider 9
12  Provider 12
14  Provider 14
16  Provider 16
```

You could use the following possible queries to get time slot information and show the provider information. You could pass the INTERVAL type and its value into the query based on some logic in your code before executing the query. By looping in your code you can gather up all the time slots you were interested in at the moment.

```
SELECT '60 Minute Slot', p.name, t.from_time, t.to_time, t.day 
FROM time_slots t 
JOIN providers p ON p.id = t.provider_id
WHERE DATE_ADD(from_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) = to_time
```

RESULT:

```
60 Minute Slot  Provider 7  2015-01-03 10:00:00 2015-01-03 11:00:00 2
60 Minute Slot  Provider 9  2015-01-03 11:00:00 2015-01-03 12:00:00 1
60 Minute Slot  Provider 12 2015-01-03 13:00:00 2015-01-03 14:00:00 2


SELECT '30 Minute Slot', p.name, t.from_time, t.to_time, t.day 
FROM time_slots t 
JOIN providers p ON p.id = t.provider_id
WHERE DATE_ADD(from_time, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) = to_time
```

RESULT:

```
30 Minute Slot  Provider 14 2015-01-03 10:00:00 2015-01-03 10:30:00 3
```

You can check out the MySQL DATE functions here:

[MySQL DATE Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)